# select multiple separately columns by iloc in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, select, multiple-columns, rows

my file contains 15 columns and 10 rows.
I want to select some columns between them like this (1:5 and 7:11 and 13:15).
I wrote it similer to:

```
'df.iloc[: ,[1:6,7:12,13:]]'
```

or

```
'df.iloc[: ,[[1:6],[7:12],[13:]]]'
```

but none of them worked. I have challenge.

may someone help?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `np.r_` to have slice notation:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=list('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'))
df1 = df.iloc[:, np.r_[1:5, 7:11, 13:15]]
print(df1)

# Output
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [B, C, D, E, H, I, J, K, N, O]
Index: []
```